# which guard does laravel uses for authentication for default?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have made a simple authentication with default laravel configurations.
My default guard is set to `web` guard.

```
 'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
```

My authentication works perfectly. Now when I put this route.

```
 Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {

    // Users
    Route::get('users/me', 'UserController@me')->name('users.me'); 

   //...below routes.
```

This route is returning the exception `unauthenticated`. 
But when I pass the guard as `auth:api` here in the middleware, it works. 
So I just want to know over which guard was my user authenticated. Since default is mentioned is `web` and I have not added `guard()` method on laravel to change the guard, why it was not taking the default web one? 
Is it because it is mentioned in the `api` routes?
And if it is so, how come does it work with `auth:api` anyway when I have not authenticated my user over that guard.

And this is my web and api middleware groups:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
            'slowresponse',
        ],
    ];
```

Comment: which file is this route defined in?

Comment: This route is defined in api.php file

Comment: api.php will use the api middleware: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#basic-routing

Comment: But the question I am asking is when I have authenticated my user over the default guard, then why does auth:api is giving me the authenticated user

Answer (score 0):

When attaching the auth middleware to a route, you may also specify which guard should be used to authenticate the user. For this you can specify in controller's constructor

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth:api');
}
```

or  you can specify in middleware as you have done.
For information you can refer documentation 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication

Comment: I was asking that I have not modified any default settings for authentication. So it must have setup my authentication info over the `web` guard right? Since the default guard mentioned in `web`. So why it is allowing me on `api` guard and its blocking me on `web` guard.?